# BehaviorSubject subscriber gets same next() element multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I'm using a shareDataService using **BehaviorSubject** like below. My problem is that every time I call the service's **next()** method the listener subscription in any other component is called several times, looks like it received the same message several times. Is this expected behavior? How to prevent it?

The service is a singleton.
I do not call **changeMessage** multiple times

```
@Injectable()
export class ShareDataService {

    messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(someData);
    currentMessage: Observable = this.messageSource.asObservable();
    changeMessage(message) {
        this.messageSource.next(message);
    }

}
```

Subscription in component

```
ngDoCheck() {
    this.shareDataService.currentMessage
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe((message) => {
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you log the order of the success callbacks from all subscriptions and show us? BehaviorSubject is supposed to emit the last (Previously emitted data and the current emitted data as well) But Just to make sure please show the logs which will contain all occurences of success callbacks

Comment: `next(...)` sends the value to all observers (subscribers). You might be creating multiple subscriptions in the same component.

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually subscribe?

Comment: @DavidR - just added

Comment: @martin - what do you mean? I only subscribe once in multiple components

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A new subscription is added every time [`ngDoCheck()`](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) is called. Try using [`first()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/first) to only get the value once and then automatically unsubscribe.

```js
ngDoCheck() {
    this.shareDataService.currentMessage
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((message) => {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

The next time `ngDoCheck` is triggered, it adds another one-time subscription.

---

If your only intention of the subscription is to get the current value on change detection, you can also add a simple get() function to your ShareDataService to just return its current value.

```js
get() {
    return this.messageSource.getValue();
}
```

Comment: I now what the issues is now! It is now sending multiple messages, it just gets triggered on change detection!

Comment: @Willys I think,, because both have an active subscription, so when one of them triggers next(). both the subscriptions fire, and causing both reloads() to fire (again).

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal Thanks for reply. What about the solution regarding to that issue? I created subject and get event for each method but I am not sure if it is a good idea? Could you pls post your suggestion to that question?

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try calling the `unsubscribe` in your `ngOnDestroy()` lifecycle hook

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.shareDataService.currentMessage.unsubscribe();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I also faced similar issue and i find I did not destroyed my `next()`.

Please check below code and add it in your `onDestroy`. I hope it may help you!

`ngOnDestroy() {
    this.messageSource.next();
}`

All The Best!!!